# Add git submodule as reference to existing solution in VS

Tags: git, visual-studio, git-submodules, projects-and-solutions

Lets say I have a submodule repo:

```
_git/DbModel (only source code indexed. No /bin or /obj folders)
```

And two projects which need DbModel as reference library:

```
_git/TTT
_git/TPM
```

I've already added DbModel as submodule via GitBash to both of them

```
 git submodule add https://RepoPath/_git/DbModel
```

And my local repos now look like this:

```
Source\Repos\TTT\TTT.sln
Source\Repos\TTT\DbModel\DbModel.sln

Source\Repos\TPM\TPM.sln
Source\Repos\TPM\DbModel\DbModel.sln
```

My Team Explorer shows two different solutions which are available now and I can switch between them easily.

But. Maybe this is a kinda newbie question...

I don't know how to add DbModel solution as reference to TPM and TTT!
When I click "Add Reference" -> "Browse" in VS I can only add ".dll, .tlb, .olb, .ocx, .exe, .manifest" as "reference files.

How is it supposed to work? Should I compile sub module solution every time and add .dll as reference? I need source code to be added.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

For those who will be interested in this:

```
git submodule add https://RepoPath/_git/DbModel
git submodule init   //this is IMPORTANT
git submodule update
```

and then add existing project in your solution from newly created folder. Like that:

```
 Source\Repos\TPM\DbModel\DbModel\DbModel.csproj
```

P.S.

```
Source\Repos\TPM\                  solution root folder (with main project sln file inside it)
Source\Repos\TPM\DbModel           submodule root folder (with submodule sln file)
Source\Repos\TPM\DbModel\DbModel   submodule project folder (with csproj file)
```