# In Visual Studio, when working on a project with more than one repository, how do I make the repo A acknowledge the repo B?

Tags: c#, git, visual-studio, repo

I have repo A and repo B, they're in different folders, but repo A uses a namespace from repo B, how would I make this connection in Visual Studio 2022? Is there a way, other than including all files in the same project?

Comment: In .Net there are *solutions* which can contain *projects*. Within a solution, projects can interact insofar as there are references made between the projects, which link together the dll's for the individual projects. This being said, are there projects within the same solution? if so, right click the "references" in the solution explorer, hit "add new reference" and point to the .dll that the project needs. If its external, you need to also point to the .dll of the external project but of course you have to locate where you stored it

Comment: Better question, why do you have a single application that has source code (rather than nuget packages) over multiple git repositories?

Comment: Can you clarify why git / repos is important to the question? Maybe explain what would you do differently if those files/projects in "different folders" are not part of any git repo?

Comment: See; [How to Add References to Your Visual Studio Project](https://www.webucator.com/article/how-to-add-references-to-your-visual-studio-projec/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you need to include the project (.csproj) from repo B in the Solution (.sln) of repo A. Then, in the project from repo A, you need to add a project reference to project B.

To do this, follow these steps:

1. In the Solution that contains the project from repo A, right click on the Solution and choose Add --> Existing Project
2. Navigate to the folder where your .csproj of repo B exists and select the .csproj, then hit OK
3. In your Solution, in project A right click on Dependencies and select "Add Project Reference"
4. Select project B

Now, your project from repo A references the project from repo B and can use its APIs.

That's the simple way. The drawback is that this will only work locally, because it depends on the folder setup and the relative paths of the projects from the different repos.

You could also try submodules if you work with Git as described here: [Add git submodule as reference to existing solution in VS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28273980/add-git-submodule-as-reference-to-existing-solution-in-vs)